# Convert String to requested Nullable data type

Tags: string-conversion

**convert a String based value** to any requested format returned as **Nullable data type** is required for need including but not limited to WCF QueryString parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the following code, which takes a **string value** and returns the converted value as a **Nullable requested datatype**

```
Public Function GetStringValueOrNull(Of T As Structure)(ByVal sInputString As String) As Object
    Try
        'Validate sInputString and proceed
        If sInputString IsNot Nothing Then
            'Input String found, validate length to better ensure validity
            If sInputString.Length > 0 Then
                'Valid input found, proceed
                Dim Result As Object
                'Convert string to requested format
                Result = CType(Convert.ChangeType(sInputString, GetType(T)), T)
                'Return Value
                Return Result
            Else
                'String length is 0, return Nothing
                Return Nothing
            End If
        Else
            'No string input found, return Nothing
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error occurred, return Nothing
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```